# Magnetic field and frame of reference

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, charge, relative-motion

A charged particle moves with a velocity near a wire carrying an electric current,and suppose I see the particle from a frame moving with same velocity in the same direction . I will see the charge at rest . So,will the magnetic force becomes zero **in this frame**?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP doesn't show any effort to understand by her/himself what's going on.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question lacks basic research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the magnetic force will be zero, but an electric field will be present in the moving frame to make sure the same force is present in both frames.